# Conditions for the invertibility of a left stochastic matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, conditional-probability, stochastic-matrices

Say we have two random variables $X$, $Y$. They are discrete variables (or discretization of continuous variables), both with $k$ categories. Define the [left stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) as $P(X|Y)_{ij}:=p(x_i|y_j)$ with shape $k \times k$.

My question is what's the equivalent condition for $P(X|Y)$ to be invertible? Does the invertibility need any constraints on the probability distribution of $p(x)$, $p(y)$, or $p(x,y)$?

I found some similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016751/a-left-stochastic-matrix-implies-the-solution-to-ax-x-is-non-trivial) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408441/condition-on-the-probabilities-for-the-j-times-j-matrix-prx-j-mid-y-k). However, neither of them answers my question.

References, if any, are appreciated.